# Extract table using rvest from website

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to use rvest to extract data from table. Following is the code I am using

```
mcurl<-read_html("http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/tataconsultancyservices/balance-sheetVI/TCS#TCS")
```

Using the following code I am only able to get the header instead of the content of the entire table.

```
html_table(html_nodes(mcurl, "table.table4")[2],header=FALSE,fill=TRUE)
[[1]]
                                                  X1                                                 X2
1 Balance Sheet of Tata Consultancy Services ------------------- in Rs. Cr. -------------------


html_table(html_nodes(mcurl, "table")[4],header=FALSE,fill=TRUE)
[[1]]
                                          X1                                                 X2
1 Balance Sheet of Tata Consultancy Services ------------------- in Rs. Cr. -------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why `rvest` struggles with this one, but you can use `readHTMLTable` from the `XML` package to do the same thing...

```
library(XML)
tables <- readHTMLTable("http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/tataconsultancyservices/balance-sheetVI/TCS#TCS")

head(tables[[5]],10)
                                 Mar 17    Mar 16    Mar 15    Mar 14    Mar 13
1                                  <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
2                               12 mths   12 mths   12 mths   12 mths   12 mths
3                                  <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
4    EQUITIES AND LIABILITIES                                              <NA>
5         SHAREHOLDER'S FUNDS                                              <NA>
6        Equity Share Capital    197.00    197.04    195.87    195.87    195.72
7    Preference Share Capital      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
8         Total Share Capital    197.00    197.04    195.87    195.87    295.72
9        Reserves and Surplus 77,825.00 58,669.82 45,220.57 43,856.01 32,266.53
10 Total Reserves and Surplus 77,825.00 58,669.82 45,220.57 43,856.01 32,266.53
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning about readHTMLTable. I am trying to achieve a bit more than just extracting data from the table shown on this page. There is a link to the right of the table 'Previous Years'. Clicking that would lead to another set of data but the same URL which I want to extract as well using html_session and hence would like to use rvest to extract the data but will face a constraint if I use readHTMLTable using url.